# Is it possible to play Far Cry 4 co-op with players on other systems?

Tags: ps3, ps4, far-cry-4

I own PS3 version and my friend owns PS4. Is it possible for us to play coop together? What about PC or Xbox interactions?

Comment: Not my knowledge, I don't even think there's a AAA game that actually has cross platform multiplayer.

Comment: @vkvau the only one I know of is Portal 2. PC/Mac/PS3 playable.

Comment: @tombull89 that's why I mentioned triple A titles, I wouldn't see Portal 2 as one. But thanks for the heads up, I didn't know that.

Comment: @vkvau really? why not? Portal 1 I would agree with, but Portal 2 had a bigger budget, bigger dev team, and arguably more anticpation.

Comment: @tombull89 maybe I underrate Valve but I'll see them as triple A when I see HL3. Personally I like Valve, much more so than any of those I'd call triple A companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no opportunity for cross-platform play in any version of Far Cry 4.

Answer (score -1):

Players on Xbox One can have co-op interactions with those playing on PC. However I haven't found evidence of this applying to PlayStation as well as Xbox.

Comment: What source do you have for your information?  It contradicts an earlier answer.